# vagrant with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed vagrant and up a machine with

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
```

When I check the linux specs, It was showing ubuntu 12

I want to install ubuntu 16.04 
what should I do now ?

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and also note hashicorp/precise64 is pretty old box so its not worth considering.

If you're looking got ubuntu 12 you should look at xenial box. The following box is the latest to be used https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64

so you should replace in your Vagrantfile by

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
```

delete your existing box and restart

```
vagrant destroy -f
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple upgrade the ubuntu too in your terminal.

Here is another solution:

vagrant destroy -f
vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64
vagrant up

Ref: https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64